# Why opening file for binary access is "meaningless" on Unix, nor the "+" for both read/write?

Tags: files, filesystems, c

I am reading The C Programming Language (2nd Edition). On page 157 and 158 the author gives a code snippet of `fopen` in the Unix system. At the end of the snippet the author added:

> In particular, our `fopen` does not recognize the "b" that signals binary access, since that is *meaningless* on UNIX systems, nor the "+" that permits both reading and writing.

Why does the author say it's meaningless? (The "b" and "+" mentioned here are file access modes)

Comment: As I understand it, [binary mode is a Windows thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307057/how-to-read-a-binary-file-in-c-video-images-or-text) having to do with translation of end-of-line characters.

Comment: @Renan What does "translation of end-of-line chars" mean exactly? Sorry I am new to UNIX.

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some non-Unix systems treat binary and text files in different ways. For example under DOS, Windows and OS/2 (which wouldn’t have been relevant when `fopen` was designed, but serve as useful examples), opening a file in text mode and writing to it will convert line endings from “C” convention (`\n`) to whatever the platform requires. On other systems, opening a file in binary mode will cause it to be processed in records. This is what `fopen`’s “b” flag controls: files opened without it are opened in text mode, files opened with it are opened in binary mode. Since Unix-style systems don’t have this distinction, “b” is ignored (and doesn’t cause an error).

My copy of the book doesn’t mention “+”, but I’m guessing `fopen` didn’t support it then ([it does now](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html)).

Answer (score 4):

According to [the POSIX specification of `fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/fopen.html) (which did not exist when that book was written):

> The character `b` shall have no effect, but is allowed for ISO C standard conformance.

The `b` mode must be accepted, but it has no effect on a POSIX system.

Furthermore, the `+` mode:

> When a file is opened with update mode (`+` as the second or third character in the mode argument), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream.

So that definitely has an effect even on a POSIX system.

Note that the C programming language has changed a bit since the K&R book was written.

Comment: POSIX wasn’t a thing when K&R wrote their book...

Comment: @StephenKitt Ah, yes, but the question wonders why they (the `b` and `+` modes) _are_ meaningless.